# how do I create a string using a backslash and a variable in python?

Tags: python, string, variables, backslash

I'm trying to execute this command on a Windows machine:

```
dir \\hostname\sapmnt\SID\SYS\profile\SID_*04_hostname /b /a-d
```

So far, I have this code:

```
cmd_drive = r"\\"
local_hostname = "hostname"
current_sid = "SID"
currentline_instance_number = "04"
cmd_pf = os.path.join(cmd_drive, local_hostname, "sapmnt", current_sid, "SYS", "profile")
cmd_pf = cmd_pf + str(current_sid) + "_*" + str(currentline_instance_number) + "_" + str(currentline_host)
cmd_pf = "dir " + cmd_pf + " /b /a-d"
print(cmd_pf)
```

which produces this output:

```
dir \\hostname\sapmnt\SID\SYS\profileSID_*04_hostname /b /a-d
```

So, I need a backslash before the final part of the string (`"SID_*04_hostname /b /a-d"`)

Comment: use '\"' before and after

Comment: This only works on windows, anyway, so there's no benefit in using `os.path.join`, by the way

Comment: I assume you are building a value to use with something like `os.system`. Use the `subprocess` module instead, and you don't need to build the string in the first place. `subprocess.run(["dir", path, '/b', '/a-d'])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a "\\" to create a backslash in the desired place:

```
cmd_drive = r"\\"
    local_hostname = "hostname"
    current_sid = "SID"
    currentline_instance_number = "04"
    cmd_pf = os.path.join(cmd_drive, local_hostname, "sapmnt", current_sid, "SYS", "profile")
    cmd_pf = cmd_pf + "\\" + str(current_sid) + "_*" + str(currentline_instance_number) + "_" + str(currentline_host)
    cmd_pf = "dir " + cmd_pf + " /b /a-d"
    print(cmd_pf)`
```